How can one pray with Long Covid, chronic fatigue syndrome, fibromyalgia and concentration issues?
Like what do I do the whole body hurts and cramps I can't focus on anything hours just pass and I dont know where they went sleep sucks and destroys me only more rathr than helping.
I cant work pain meddles with performance and my spontaneously self deleting memory makes me get fired within days I have no more money for insurance and can't even get medication.
What do I look out for when I just have no strength and can only lie in bed and exercise causes only more cramps and pain, when I barely can even keep myself and my home clean?
I must pray I must clean I must work but I am basically internally intoxicated and can't manage anything, its like waking up from anesthesia and never getting rid of the intoxication in the first few minutes.
I suppose only a miracle can save me now. I don't have any reaction to quran or ruqya except for making me calm and restful. If it was jinn related there should have been something right?
May Allah curse, if engineered in a lab, the inventors and first spreaders of the coronavirus and throw them into the deepest of Jahannam if they deserve it.

Questions asking for personal advice are off-topic.
